# how to create full width submenu in css

Tags: css

[Image Screen shot - need to adjust width and height of the sub menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NZIQf.png)
I want to create a submenu which will have the full width of the screen from left to right.
But below CSS is not working for me, instead it is starting from Home.
I tried by putting width as 100 %, display as block etc,  but still, it is not working for me.
HTML

```css
    .mtmegamenu .menu-items {
     opacity: 0;
     transform-origin: 0 0 0;
     transition: all 0.8s ease 0s;
     left: 0 !important;
     -ms-transform: scaleY(0);
     -webkit-transform: scaleY(0);
     -moz-transform: scaleY(0);
     -o-transform: scaleY(0);
     transform: scaleY(0);
    }
    .mtmegamenu li:hover .menu-items {
     opacity: 1;
     -ms-transform: scaleY(1);
     -webkit-transform: scaleY(1);
     -moz-transform: scaleY(1);
     -o-transform: scaleY(1);
     transform: scaleY(1);
    }
    .mtmegamenu {
     position: relative;
     margin: auto 0px auto 30px;
     font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
     height: 40px;
    }
    .mtmegamenu a:focus {
     outline: 0
    }
    .mtmegamenu>ul {
     display: inline-block;
     clear: both;
     margin: 0
    }
    .mtmegamenu>ul {
     height: 28px;
     padding: 0;
     text-align: left
    }
    .mtmegamenu>ul>li {
     display: inline-block;
     font-size: 15px;
     text-transform: uppercase;
     margin-right: 1px;
     background: none !important;
     margin-right: 30px;
    }
```

```html
  <div class="container">
      <div class="row">

          <div class="col-md-10 col-sm-11">
              <div class="mtmegamenu">
                  <ul class="hidden-xs">
                      <li class="mt-root demo_custom_link_cms">
                          <div class="mt-root-item">
                              <a href="index.html">
                                  <div class="title title_font"><span class="title-text">Home</span></div>
                              </a>
                          </div>
                      </li>
                      <li class="mt-root">
                          <div class="mt-root-item">
                              <a href="#">
                                  <div class="title title_font"><span class="title-text">Mens</span></div>
                              </a>
                          </div>
                          <ul class="menu-items col-lg-12">
                              <li class="menu-item depth-1 menucol-1-6 ">
                                  <div class="title title_font"> <a href="#">Fashion</a></div>
                                  <ul class="submenu">
                                      <li class="menu-item">
                                          <div class="title"> <a href="shop_grid.html">Women</a></div>
                                      </li>
                                      <li class="menu-item">
                                          <div class="title"> <a href="shop_grid.html">Men</a></div>
                                      </li>

                                  </ul>
                              </li>

                          </ul>
                      </li>

                  </ul>

              </div>
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>
```

Same as we see in myntra or flipkart any ecommerce website

Comment: HTML is as below

Comment: plz add html code.

Comment: .mtmegamenu {position: initial;}

Comment: it is not working, it is starting from home and ending to its last parent menu

Answer (score 1):

You should use 'vw' attr to fill all screen width:

```
#wide-div {
  width: 100vw;
}
```

Comment: #wide-div is which element in my case , it is ul or li

Comment: denpends on which element you mean. If you want li element to be 100% of your screen you should use my advice for it.

Comment: If it has helped you, please set my answer as answer.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this?

```css
.mtmegamenu .menu-items {
    opacity: 0;
    transform-origin: 0 0 0;
    transition: all 0.8s ease 0s;
    left: 0 !important;
    -ms-transform: scaleY(0);
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(0);
    -moz-transform: scaleY(0);
    -o-transform: scaleY(0);
    transform: scaleY(0);
}
.mtmegamenu li:hover .menu-items {
    opacity: 1;
    -ms-transform: scaleY(1);
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(1);
    -moz-transform: scaleY(1);
    -o-transform: scaleY(1);
    transform: scaleY(1);
}
.mtmegamenu {
    position: relative;
    margin: auto 0px auto 30px;
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
    height: 40px;
}
.mtmegamenu a:focus {
    outline: 0
}
.mtmegamenu>ul {
    display: inline-block;
    clear: both;
    margin: 0
}
.mtmegamenu>ul {
    height: 28px;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: left
}
.mtmegamenu>ul>li {
    display: inline; /* inline */
    font-size: 15px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    margin-right: 1px;
    background: none !important;
    margin-right: 30px;
    float: left; /*added*/
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">

        <div class="col-md-10 col-sm-11">
            <div class="mtmegamenu">
                <ul class="hidden-xs">
                    <li class="mt-root demo_custom_link_cms">
                        <div class="mt-root-item">
                            <a href="index.html">
                                <div class="title title_font"><span class="title-text">Home</span></div>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li class="mt-root">
                        <div class="mt-root-item">
                            <a href="#">
                                <div class="title title_font"><span class="title-text">Mens</span></div>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                        <ul class="menu-items col-lg-12">
                            <li class="menu-item depth-1 menucol-1-6 ">
                                <div class="title title_font"> <a href="#">Fashion</a></div>
                                <ul class="submenu">
                                    <li class="menu-item">
                                        <div class="title"> <a href="shop_grid.html">Women</a></div>
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="menu-item">
                                        <div class="title"> <a href="shop_grid.html">Men</a></div>
                                    </li>

                                </ul>
                            </li>

                        </ul>
                    </li>

                </ul>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: no , When mouse hover on mens ,full width submenu should get display

Comment: I not sure what are you expecting. do you have any example or image?

Comment: please view image attached, If u see submenu is coming from home ,it should come from left of the screen ,also i need to adjust height